# Code coverage - eliminating false positives

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, code-coverage, jasmine, gruntjs

I'm using istanbul (via grunt, jasmine and phantomJS) to generate code coverage reports for my unit tests. I'm getting what I would call false positives caused by modules which have the module I'm testing as a dependency calling its methods, i.e.

`module1.js` loads `module2.js` as a dependency. Unit tests for module1 call `module1.method`, which in turn calls `module2.method`. When I look at the code coverage report `module2.method` is highlighted in green even though there are no tests for it.

Is this something I should be concerened about, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this as well but, I think this is the right behavior. Code coverage only means that the code was executed during the test. Not that the code was part of an assertion.

Answer (score 2):

I created this grunt task to help identify files which aren't explicitly covered by their own test suite

```
grunt.registerTask('missingSpecs', 'Missing specs list', function (env, limit) {
    var specs = getFileList(getSpecs(env)),
        src = getFileList(getSrc(env)),
        missingSpecs = [];

    for (var file in src) {
        if (specs.indexOf(src[file]) === -1) {
            missingSpecs.push(src[file]);
        }
    }
    if (missingSpecs.length) {
        console.log(
            '\n******************************************************************************************************\n' +
            '*** The following common js files aren\'t covered by any tests. They won\'t write themselves, y\'know ***\n' +
            '******************************************************************************************************\n'
            );
        missingSpecs.sort(function () {
            return Math.random() - 0.5;
        }).slice(0,limit).forEach(function (file) {
            console.log(file);
        });
    }

})
```

Where getFileList uses grunt.file.expand and some regex to get lists of module names.